# Efficiently filling a block in a matrix using StaticArrays

Tags: optimization, julia

When using static arrays, I noticed that there is a huge efficiency loss depending on how you convert/create static matrices:

```
using StaticArrays

code_fast() = SMatrix{2,2}(1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0 , 1.0); code_fast(); @btime code_fast();
>> 0.026 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

code_slow() = SMatrix{2,2}([1.0  1.0 ; 1.0  1.0]); code_slow(); @btime code_slow();
>> 45.371 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
```

The slow code can be easily corrected, however, by setting

```
code_slow() = @SMatrix [1.0  1.0 ; 1.0  1.0]
```

for which it is not slow anymore and gets as fast as `code_fast`. The problem is that for using the `@SMatrix` macro one must really write the components of matrix to be converted by hand, or else use `rand`, `zeros` or `ones`. If this cannot be done, then I could find no option besides using `SMatrix{n,n}`, which renders using static arrays so slow they become useless.

Concretely, the type of functions I need to optimize look like

```
test(n,G,mat) = begin mat[1+n:2n,1:n] = G; mat end
```

where `G` is a complicated static matrix that is calculated inside another function. I need to stuff this matrix inside `mat` as a block, and I need the output to be also static (this operation is performed billions of times). By converting to a static one at the end, that is:

```
test_SA(n,G,mat)  = begin mat[1+n:2n,1:n] = G; SMatrix{2n,2n}(mat) end
```

I run into the aforementioned problem of `SMatrix` being too slow:

```
n=2
G = @SMatrix ones(Float64,n,n)
mat = Matrix{Float64}(I,2n,2n)

test(n,G,mat); @btime test($n,$G,$mat);          # 17.821 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
test_SA(n,G,mat); @btime test_SA($n,$G,$mat_mm); # 1.825 μs (22 allocations: 1.36 KiB)
```

Can someone please explain what is going on, and how to correct it? I would really like to use static arrays here, since all the other modules in the code run *much* faster precisely because of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the name indicates the size of a `StaticArray` should be static and in your code it is dynamic not static. Your problem can be narrowed to:

```
julia> @btime  SMatrix{2*$n,2*$n}($mat);
  1.310 μs (22 allocations: 1.36 KiB)
```

What to do about it? The first option is to have fixed sizes that will be known at the compile time:

```
julia> @btime SMatrix{4,4}($mat);
  1.599 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

This will be not always convenient so fortunately there is another reasonable option - create the target type beforehead (and perhaps re-use it 1 billion times).

```
MySMatrix =  SMatrix{2n,2n}
```

Once created it will be blazing fast:

```
julia> @btime $MySMatrix($mat)
  1.799 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
4×4 SArray{Tuple{4,4},Float64,2,16} with indices SOneTo(4)×SOneTo(4):
 1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
 1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0
 1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0
```

If you are generating the static arrays you must also take a look at `sacollect` which as fast as hell as well:

```
julia> @btime StaticArrays.sacollect($MySMatrix, i*j for i in 1:4, j in 1:4)
  1.399 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
4×4 SArray{Tuple{4,4},Int64,2,16} with indices SOneTo(4)×SOneTo(4):
 1  2   3   4
 2  4   6   8
 3  6   9  12
 4  8  12  16
```

Comment: Thanks! Defining the type beforehand solved the problem for me. I didn't notice the type definition itself was the cause of the problem!

Comment: This behavior seems to be not well documented. Yet it is natural and critical to understanding how to use StaticArrays in practice.